# Get DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode value from String

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a small question about VB.net in Visual studio. I'm loading a combobox using:

```
cbxAutofit.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode))
```

I want on item.select to apply that "DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode" to a DataGridView on th same form but i'm not doing something right, because when I use the code below, I get the error Unhandled exception.
How can I convert the resulting strint to that system enum? Or is there a way I can add the integer value of each DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode as either a second column or something similar, so I can call it?

```
Dim value As String, Res As DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode
value = cbxSheets.SelectedItem.value
Res = [Enum].Parse(GetType(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode), value)
```

Comment: Where is `value` coming from in `cbxSheets.SelectedItem.value`? Did you check what `SelectedItem` is at that point? Try with something like:  `Debug.WriteLine(cbxAutofit.SelectedItem.GetType())`. Just cast it to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode`.

Comment: `cbxAutofit` vs. `cbxSheets`, did you just use the wrong control?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Enum documentation's *Iterating Enumeration Members* section ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum#iterating-enumeration-members)):

> You can call the GetNames method to retrieve a string array containing
> the names of the enumeration members. Next, for each element of the
> string array, you can call the Parse method to convert the string to
> its equivalent enumeration value.

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Dim t = GetType(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)
cbxAutofit.DisplayMember = "Name"
cbxAutofit.ValueMember = "Value"
cbxAutofit.DataSource = [Enum].GetNames(t).Select(Function(name) New With {.Name = name, .Value = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(t, name), DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)}).ToList()
```

Then you can get the value by using:

```vb
Dim enumValue = DirectCast(cbxAutofit.SelectedValue, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a string as the `DataSource` is fine, but you need to change a couple things:

1. You had referenced another `ComboBox`, `cbxSheets`, and I guess it's just a typo
2. You are accessing the `ComboBox.SelectedItem.Value` instead of just `SelectedItem`

this is fine:

```vb
cbxAutoFit.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode))
```

Use `SelectedItem`, and access the proper `ComboBox`. Also casting to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode`, and getting the string with `ToString()` will get you the correct types.

```vb
Private Sub cbxAutoFit_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxAutoFit.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim value = cbxAutoFit.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim resultEnum = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode), value), DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode)
    Dim resultText = resultEnum.ToString()
End Sub
```

The @David solution is fine too. Compared with this, it front-loads the work vs. back-loading it. I do like that approach where the `DataSource.Value` is actually a `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode`.